# xcodebuild not work in php but works fine in command line

Tags: php, xcodebuild

As the title, I want to build the app with xcodebuild. Unexpected, the code bellow is not work in php but works fine in Command Line Tools:

```
echo '########' . exec('xcodebuild -list') . '########';
```

I check the permission of the files is 777, is the php not support the xcodebuild?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a problem with PHP not having access to the same environment variables, e.g. $PATH. Try like this:

```php
echo '########' . exec('/usr/bin/xcodebuild -list') . '########';
```